# Upload File from Flutter Web to Node.js / Express.js Server

Tags: flutter, http, file-upload, flutter-web, dio

I am working on a Flutter web project and FilePicker returns the path as null on Flutter web, so how can I create a File that I can send to Multipart for sending it to Node.js or Express.js Server?

Answer (score 6):

**PACKAGES REQUIRED**

**FLUTTER SIDE:**

1. [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)
2. [File Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)

**NODEJS SIDE:**

1. [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

**FLUTTER - PICK A FILE**

```dart
test() async {
    // * Pick a File
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    if (result != null) {
      // * cast it to bytes
      List<int> bytes = result.files.single.bytes!.cast();
      // * Get its name, will use it later.
      var name = result.files.single.name;
      // * Send it to method that will make HTTP request.
      _projectProvider.test(bytes, name);
    }
}
```

**FLUTTER - MAKE A HTTP REQUEST**

```dart
import 'dart:developer';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class ProjectProvider {
  // * constructor
  ProjectProvider() : _dio = Dio();

  // * dio
  late Response _response;
  late final Dio _dio;

  // * rest api
  final _baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:3000";

  test(List<int> bytes, String name) async {
    String extension = name.split(".").last;

    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "file": MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        bytes,
        filename: name,
        contentType: MediaType("File", extension),
      ),
    });

    _response = await _dio.post("$_baseUrl/test", data: formData);

    log("test response");
    log(_response.data.toString());
  }
}
```

**NODEJS SERVER - MULTER STORAGE SETTINGS**

```js
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./files/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    let originalName = file.originalname;
    let extension = originalName.split(".")[1];
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix + "." + extension);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

**NODEJS SERVER - POST REQUEST HANDLER**

```js
app.route("/test").post(upload.single("file"), function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.file);
});
```